# How to get real end index of string found in another string

Tags: java, apache-stringutils

I am trying to get a range of chars found in another string using Java:

```
String input = "test test2 Test3";
String substring = "test2";

int diffStart = StringUtils.indexOf(input, substring);
int diffEnd = StringUtils.lastIndexOf(input, substring);
```

I want to get

- diffStart = 5
- diffEnd = 10

But I am getting

- diffStart = 5
- diffEnd = **5**

Based on Apache's Commons [lastIndexOf](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#lastIndexOf-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) function it should work:

> public static int lastIndexOf(CharSequence seq,
> CharSequence searchSeq)
>
> Finds the last index within a CharSequence, handling null. This method
> uses String.lastIndexOf(String) if possible.
>
> StringUtils.lastIndexOf("aabaabaa", "ab") = 4

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you can write diffEnd in this way :
`diffEnd = difStart + strOutputDiff.length();`

Comment: but this approach only works for examples like your example !

Comment: Thank you Mohsen, You ar right. I have wrongly interpreted the sense of lastIndexOf.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you probably want

```
diffStart = String.valueOf(StringUtils.indexOf(strInputString02, strOutputDiff));
diffEnd = diffStart + strOutputDiff.length();
```

lastIndexOf finds the matching string, but the last instance of it.

E.g. ab1 ab2 ab3 ab4

lastindexof("ab") finds the 4th ab

indexof("ab") finds the 1st ab (position 0)

However, they always return the location of the first character.

If there is only one instance of a substring lastindexof and indexof will give the same index.

(To enhance your example more, you may also want to do some -1 checks in case the substring is not there at all)

Comment: Thank you Bruce, You are right. I have wrongly interpreted the sense of lastIndexOf